# Sympy.solve returning: " [] "

Tags: python, sympy

I was working on a program that takes an input, and solves it. I used Sympy. I assumed because this works:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
x, y = symbols("x y")
eq1 = Eq(5 + x)
eq2 = Eq(5 + y)
sol = solve((eq1, eq2),(x, y))
print(sol)
```

Gives the result:

```
{x: -5, y: -5}
```

This should work too, because I'm splitting it, formatting the code correctly, and it has the inputs of "a" and "z":

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
 
Input = input("Please give the two variables the names 'a' and 'z': ").replace("x", "*").replace("^", "**").upper().split(" = ")
a, z = symbols("a z")
othersol = solve((Input[0], Input[1]),(a, z))
print(othersol)
```

Though, when given the input:

```
5 + a = 5 + z
```

It gives the result:

```
[]
```

I want to know why it is not solving, why it doesn't work, and how I can make a program that takes an input and solves the equation given. If I need to, I will even switch my Python Library. If not, can you give the code that takes an input, and solves that equation?

Can anybody do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see what is wrong in here when you compare what you are giving as first parameter to your `solve` function.

In your working code you do like this:

```
eq1 = Eq(5 + x)
eq2 = Eq(5 + y)
sol = solve((eq1, eq2),(x, y))
```

First parameter is two `Eq` objects.

Let's see what is going on in your non-working code.

```
>>> Input = input("Please give the two variables the names 'a' and 'z': ").replace("x", "*").replace("^", "**").upper().split(" = ")
Please give the two variables the names 'a' and 'z': a+1 = zx3
>>> Input
['A+1', 'Z*3']
>>> type(Input[0])
<class 'str'>
>>> solve((Input[0], Input[1]),(a, z))
[]
```

There first parameter is tuple of two strings.

So you'd need to parse your Input-strings to Eq objects. Then you'd have working code. It may be challenging task though if you want to allow your user enter freetext input. Input in polish notation or some other more strcutured way would be much easier to parse.

--- EDIT ----

With exec it could be something like this. I Added a function to secure input a bit. This will fail if there is unknown characters in input.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
A, Z = symbols("A Z")

def secure_input(inputstring):
    known_symbols = {" ","A","Z","+","*","**","-"}
    if not all([x in known_symbols or x.isdigit() for x in inputstring]):
        raise Exception("Illegal strings in input %s"%inputstring)
    return inputstring

Input = input("Please give the two variables the names 'a' and 'z': ").replace("x", "*").replace("^", "**").upper().split(" = ")

i1 = secure_input(Input[0])
i2 = secure_input(Input[1])
exec("eq1 = Eq(%s)" % i1)
exec("eq2 = Eq(%s)" % i2)
solve((eq1,eq2),(A, Z))
```

Also, you used lower-case variable names but you said `upper()` for your input string. I changed that as well, now the code should work.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how I could do this?

Comment: Or do you have a program that already does this?

Comment: No I don't. After all, what you are looking for here is writing an interpreter for user input. It isn't an easy task. One approach would be create a string which is similar what you would write to `Eq` object constructor and call it with `exec`. But it is a very dangerous way. Executing user input makes your code vulnerable for injection attacks and a user can run any code he wants in your system. So I won't give you an example for that.

Comment: I'm just doing this for fun, I wouldn't do anything like that.

Comment: Also, well, I have done the "split" which is easier to parse.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Can you suggest a site?

Comment: Or anything that may help me?

Comment: Can you also suggest whether I should change my Python library?

Comment: Is it easier on another library?

Comment: And, what are the different types I sould change to, to parse? Other than RPN.

Comment: I am sorry for so many messages, but I am a beginner to Python, and don't know a lot.

Comment: @MiddleSchooler: I updated my answer a little bit. It isn't good way to do this anyway. And little comment for your "I'm doing this for fun". Coding for fun is the best way to learn. But it is good to learn to write secure code from start. You have good habits when you are writing your killer cloud app which will have millions of users.

Comment: And for learning. Instead of just copy the code for your project, try to understand what it really does. Preferably re-write it with some modifications.

Comment: Also, can you please post the entire code, the code in the edit doesn't work on my spyder application.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my code, and it works, Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, can you please post the way so I can return the answer as: "A = -14, Z = -9" instead of: "{A: -14, Z: -9}"? I appreciate your help.

Comment: The only thing I would suggest to your code is the formatting.

Comment: I will put an extension to your code at the bottom.

Comment: I just want to ask you, when I give the input: 5 x 4 = A + Z, it gives the result: "[]" even in your code. Why?

Comment: That is probably Sympys behaviour.

Comment: I realize why. I did research on SymPy, and it turns out it tries to turn the espression to 0. So, it couldn't turn 5 x 4 to 0, so it returned: "[]".

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
A, Z = symbols("A Z")

def secure_input(inputstring):
    known_symbols = {" ","A","Z","+","*","**","-"}
    if not all([x in known_symbols or x.isdigit() for x in inputstring]):
        raise Exception("Illegal strings in input %s"%inputstring)
    return inputstring

Input = input("Please give the two variables the names 'a' and 'z': ").replace("x", "*").replace("^", "**").upper().split(" = ")

i1 = secure_input(Input[0])
i2 = secure_input(Input[1])
exec("eq1 = Eq(%s)" % i1)
exec("eq2 = Eq(%s)" % i2)
A = solve((eq1,eq2),A)
Z = solve((eq1,eq2),Z)
print(str(A).replace("{","").replace("}", ""))
print(str(Z).replace("{","").replace("}", ""))
```